Show that $\sum_{k=1}^n{2^{2k-1}\binom{2n+1}{2k}B_{2k}(0)}=n$
Lately, I've been working on a proof (whose context is not necessary to discuss) and I only need one last thing in order to finish it. To be more specific, for completeness it would suffice to show the following identity: $$\sum_{k=1}^n{2^{2k-1}\binom{2n+1}{2k}B_{2k}(0)}=n. \tag1\label1$$
where $\operatorname{B}_{k}\left(x\right)$ is a Bernoulli Polynomial.

Which I've checked to be true for $n = 1, 2, 3$ and $4$.
However, my trivial knowledge in $\tt C\!+\!+$ does not allow me to check it computationally for way more values, given the involvement of the
Bernoulli numbers in this identity.
Although, this is enough information ( including the context of the proof I'm working on, which I'll refrain from revealing, as it is not required to do so ) to convince me that it holds true for all positive integers $n$.
So, the next step of mine would be to make an attempt at a proof.
But, my efforts so far have been fruitless and my ideas even more so.

First, I tried to work it out with summation by parts, but it quickly sent me to a dead end.
Then, I thought about an inductive proof and as you may guess it is kind of impossible to move forward by induction due to the dependence of the summand from $n$ ( in the binomial coefficient !!! ).


From there, I thought about some high end stuff like generating functions or Taylor series, because by definition
$$\frac{t}{e^t-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{B_k(0)\frac{t^k}{k!}},\tag2\label2$$
but I've no idea about how to move forward from there.
In addition, I shouldn't forget to mention that my only (useful to me so far) givens are the different (and equivalent) definitions that I found on the corresponding Wikipedia page for the Bernoulli numbers.
In particular, I know that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n{\binom{n+1}{k}B_k(0)}=\delta_{n,0}:=\begin{cases}
0, \text{if} & n>0 \\
1, \text{if} & n=0 \\
\end{cases}.\tag3\label3$$
From which, it easy to deduce that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ the following holds:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n{\binom{2n+1}{2k}B_{2k}(0)}=-\frac{1}{2}.\tag4\label4$$
Now, it is apparent that the summands of \eqref{1} and \eqref{4} look a lot alike.

If only, I was more knowledgeable about discrete methods.
Hence, I'm inclined to ask for help and/or reference requests, in case what I'm asking help for, has already been settled in the past ( not necessarily on MSE ).

C++ is hardly the language for this. Try Sage: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVjkEKwjAQRfeB3OEvk1gXEdwIvYGXqHWqIelEps39nVYUHJjN-4_Pv9OE8Uljduwv1kDvih5Lm90pBP18jB4Bt8R1TkNRwofYQYMdk3BtpSS3g6kKMhJDBn6QU09l7z-9QmsT3up7sDXWbDb_2fH8HfGSxKvj7jfOvwEldS1w&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==

Also, note that your left hand side can be rewritten as $\sum\limits_k 2^k \dbinom{2n+1}{k} B_k\left(0\right)$, up to a scalar factor of $2$ and the few odd Bernoulli numbers that are nonzero. This is likely to be much easier. In terms of the Bernoulli umbra, this is $\operatorname{eval}\left(\left(2B_-+1\right)^{2n+1}\right)$.

@darijgrinberg BRILLIANT!!! Why are they teaching us C++ at the department when this gold just exists?!?!?!

Well, you need no courses to learn Sage :)

@darijgrinberg Well, I'll have this information at the back of my mind from now on. Also, to comment on your second comment, I am completely unfamiliar with umbral calculus and I think it is an inappropriate approach for an undergrad like myself.

Actually, since you're already using Bernoulli polynomials, you can rewrite my sum $\sum\limits_k 2^k \dbinom{2n+1}{k} B_k\left(0\right)$ as $2^{2n+1} B_{2n+1}\left(1/2\right)$. But $B_{2n+1}\left(1/2\right) = 0$, since $B_m\left(-x\right) = \left(-1\right)^m B_m\left(x\right)$ for any nonnegative integer $m$ and any $x$.

@darijgrinberg Sorry, I do not seem to follow your reasoning.

I'm giving credits to @darijgrinberg because I was using the Bernoulli polynomials to approach the proof and I finally figured it out thanks to his comment.
Bernoulli polynomials are defined through Bernoulli numbers with
$$B_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}\mathrm B_{k}\,x^{n-k}$$
We can break up these into odd an even polynomials:
$$B_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{f(n)}{n \choose 2k}\mathrm B_{2k}\,x^{n-2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{g(n)}{n \choose 2k+1}\mathrm B_{2k+1}\,x^{n-2k-1}$$
where $f(n)$ is $\frac{n}{2}$ if it is even or $\frac{n-1}{2}$ if odd, and for $g(n)$, $\frac{n-1}{2}$ if odd and $n-1$ if even.
If we only want odd Bernoulli polynomials we may introduce the change of index $n\to 2n+1$:
$$B_{2n+1}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n+1 \choose 2k}\mathrm B_{2k}\,x^{2n+1-2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} {2n+1 \choose 2k+1}\mathrm B_{2k+1}\,x^{2n-2k}$$
But since $\mathrm B_{2k+1}=0$ for $k\geq 1$ then it reduces to
$$B_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n+1 \choose 2k}\mathrm B_{2k}\,x^{2n+1-2k}-\dfrac{2n+1}{2}x^{2n}$$
If we evaluate this at $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$ we get
$$B_{2n+1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n+1 \choose 2k}\mathrm B_{2k}\,2^{2k-1-2n}-\dfrac{2n+1}{2}2^{-2n}$$
According to what @darijgrinberg said, $B_{2n+1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$ and so
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{2k-1}{2n+1 \choose 2k}\mathrm B_{2k}=\dfrac{2n+1}{2}$$
And passing the $k=0$th term to the other side we end up with
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{2k-1}{2n+1 \choose 2k}\mathrm B_{2k}=n$$

That is absolutely fantastic!! Now I see what @darijgrinberg meant on his last comment. Much appreciation to both of you. Cheers!

We know that
$$
\frac{t}{e^t-1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty B_k \frac{t^k}{k!}
$$
We need to find
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2^{2k-1} \binom{2n+1}{2k} B_{2k} = \frac{(2n+1)!}{2} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{2^{2k} B_{2k}}{(2k)!} \frac{1}{(2n-2k+1)!}
$$
The right hand side is the coefficient near $t^{2n+1}$ in the product of
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^{k}B_{k}}{k!} t^{k} = \frac{2t}{e^{2t}-1}
$$
and
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} = \frac{e^t - e^{-t}}{2}
$$
So, the product itself is
$$
t\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{e^{2t}-1} = te^{-t} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^{k+1}}{k!},
$$
and the coefficient near $t^{2n+1}$ is $\frac{1}{2n!}$, meaning that the whole sum evaluates to $n+\frac{1}{2}$.
Now to get $n$ we just subtract the contribution of $k=0$, which is $\frac{1}{2}$, and we get $n$. $\square$
